# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

While I was trying to createStore in react-redux I get this strange error. I don't know why as I did this before in different app there it was working fine.

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
./src/index.js
C:/projects/facebook/facebook-react/src/index.js:14
  11 | import rootReducer from './rootReducer';
  12 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
  13 | 
> 14 | const store = createStore(
  15 |     rootReducer,
  16 |     composeWithDevtools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  17 | );
View compiled
▶ 6 stack frames were collapsed.
```

this is my file

> index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevtools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevtools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);


ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
</BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

> rootReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'; import user from './reducers/user';

export default combineReducers({
    user });
```

> reducer/user

```
import { USER_LOGGED_IN } from '../types';

export default function user(state = {}, action={}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_LOGGED_IN:
            return action.user;
        default:
            return state;
    } }
```

Comment: Information is not suffice to conclude the cause.

Comment: is your `rootReducer` a function or an object?

Comment: @SagarKharche is the information sufficent now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue: I could get it to work on a test app and couldnt move it across to my main project. Checked all of the code 100 times and researched widely but couldnt find anything to make connect() work without it throwing "TypeError: Object(…) is not a function"

In the end all that was required was to update react and react-DOM in my main project as i was running a new version of redux with old react.

Just run the below in your project folder.

```
npm update
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are viewing this message now that is around 2020 with the same problem above then make sure in import statement

```
import { composeWithDevtools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
```

should be

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
```

The name is case-sensitive. You need to make sure that you get the capitalization of "DevTools" correct.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  I spelt it as composedWithDevTools.  Note the extra 'd'

Answer (score 2):

This error ocurred when:

1. react-redux not available in runtime.
   Please check that it correctly bundled or available as global (if used from CDN)
2. versions of react, redux incompatible with react-redux. Update some of them to the latest

Comment: Yes, this is what my issue was. I had imported connect from mongoose and not redux!

Answer (score 1):

I was using react-boilerplate library and did "npm update" which broke "aws-amplify" for some reason. So I unstaged my package.json and package-lock.json and went back to the previous package.json and package-lock.json ran "npm install".
Suddenly "Object(...) is not a function" error got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error came from misspelling 'composeWithDevTools' I was trying to import 'compose**Witdh**DevTools' silly me... do check that import.

You can also hover all your imports and see if you actually import the correct methods.. for composeWithDevTools when you do that it should look like this:

```
(alias) function composeWithDevTools<StoreExt, StateExt>(...funcs: Array<StoreEnhancer<StoreExt>>): StoreEnhancer<StoreExt> (+1 overload)
import composeWithDevTools
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux/lib/redux';
```

I dont know why but it's work, I was create a rails app with react and react-redux. I got this error 2 times on different apps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after 2 hours of reading the code I realized that it was in the definition of the object that we passed to createSlice().
What I had written was:

```
const notificationsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'notifications',
  initialState: [],
  reducer: {...},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {...},
})
```

If you look closely you will see that "reducer" is written without the "s" at the end. So it should be like this:

```
const notificationsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'notifications',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {...},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {...},
})
```

The error was triggered when a component tried to dispatch an action that was generated by that reducer.