# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when invoking createStore

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was trying to use the createStore from redux to create a store for this app and it was okay until i started applying multiple store enhancers in it. So i get this error [TypeError: Object(...) is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO7sd.png)

the dependencies are

```js
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-redux": "^7.1.3",
"react-scripts": "1.1.5",
"redux": "^4.0.4",
```

this is the index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import firebaseConfig from './config/firebaseConfig'

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    compose( 
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})),
        reduxFirestore(firebaseConfig),
        reactReduxFirebase(firebaseConfig)
    )
);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}> <App /> </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

i don't know how to move forward without solving this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in react-redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036086/typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-in-react-redux)

Comment: i have tried it already, it doesn't seem to solve the problem